# Apache HTTP server dejó de funcionar por muchas conexiones

Tags: php, apache, xampp

tengo un problema con el Xampp. Tengo un servidor Windows server 2016 con xampp, todo corria tranquilo hasta que se habilitó conexiones de afuera (ya no de la intranet) a la aplicación. Ahora tenemos conexiones de afuera e intranet y a cada cierto tiempo el Apache deja de funcionar. La aplicación corre en PHP.
Otro tema es que usa el CPU y la RAM casi al máximo, tengo un Intel Xeon 2640 de 2.40 GHz con 12 GB de RAM.
Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

Comment: De acuerdo a las [preguntas frecuentes](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html), XAMPP no es adecuado para ambiente de producción, por lo que deberías buscar otra alternativa. Según [esta respuesta](https://serverfault.com/a/364484) (en inglés), lo recomendable es instalar cada componente por separado.

Comment: Gracias Triby por la recomendación.

Comment: Xampp está diseñado [para desarrollo](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/faq_windows.html). Para producción instala Apache normalmente o un Nginx, adicional el módulo [PHP FPM](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+fpm) ayudará enormemente al servidor. Creo que en Nginx te pide si o si PFM, en apache hay que configurarlo. En ese sentido te conviene un servidor en Linux (aunque no es obligatorio) donde esos componentes se van amarrando automáticamente.

Comment: Gracias aeportugal, en realidad no acostubro a trabajar con Linux, vere la forma de instalar de manera independiente el PHP y el Apache, gracias.

Comment: Quizá te estén bombardeando con mogollón de solicitudes.

Comment: Me sumo a la sugerencia de @aeportugal, si no tienes otros servicios que requieran trabajar bajo Windows, lo ideal sería un servidor Linux.